# How can I simplify this expression (razor)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

How can I simplify this razor expression:

```
    @if (Model.CarImages == null)
    {
        <text>var CarImages = [];</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>var CarImages = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CarImages));</text>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the ideal approach would be for `CarImages` to simply never be `null`.  Initialize it in the model:

```
public IList<SomeType> CarImages { get; set; } = new List<SomeType>();
```

I mainly guessed on the types, use whatever collections/objects you're using.  But the point is to initialize it.  However you're populating it, make sure you're always setting a valid list.  Even if it's an empty one.

Then your view is simpler:

```
var CarImages = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CarImages));
```

Basically, move the logic to the model as much as possible.  The view should do little (if anything) more than just bind to model data, it shouldn't have to internally check the validity of that data.  The model is responsible for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this using a shorthand if else sentence as such:

```
<text>
    var CarImages = @(Model.CarImages == null ? [] :
    Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CarImages)));
</text>
```